# Writing a Function to check for Divisibility

Tags: python, eclipse, function, pydev

I am trying to write a function that checks if an int passed into my method in the main file is divisible by 3 and 5.

I am having trouble because I am not sure what to use to check the condition in my method, since the value is passed in via the method call in the main file.

I am also not sure I am using the % operator correctly to check if the value is divisible by 3 and 5.  Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Main:

```
from divisibleByPackage.isDivisibleBy import *

count_passed = 0
count_failed = 0
if (is_divisible(15) == True):
print("Test #1 passed")
count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #1 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(1) == False):
    print("Test #2 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #2 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(5) == False):
    print("Test #3 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #3 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(0) == True):
    print("Test #4 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #4 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1

    print(str(count_passed) + " tests passed and " + str(count_failed) + " tests failed")
```

Function imported from PyDev package:

```
def is_divisible():
    number1 = 3
    number2 = 5

    if (number1 % == 0 && number2 % == 0)
        return True
    else
        return False
```

I was expecting the method call in my main to return true or false based on the condition, but Eclipse is saying my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors in the code :

1. The function is defined not to take arguments, however in the tests, it is called with an argument.
2. `&&` is not an operator in Python, `and` is used instead.
3. The second operand to the `%` operator is missing. The `%` is a binary operator, meaning it works with two operands. Example `3%2`

The function should be written as

```py
def is_divisible(number):

    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 % 3 == 0
```

means a number is divisible by 3

```
number1 % 5 == 0
```

means a number is divisible by 5

```
 number1 % 3 == 0 and number1 % 5 == 0
 # NOTE it is NOT && for 'and' in python
```

means it is divisible by both 3 AND 5

```
 number1 % 3 == 0 or number1 % 5 == 0
```

means it is divisible by either 3 or 5 or maybe both

```
 number1 % == 0
```

is just a syntax error (also `&&` is not correct in python)

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to accept a parameter, which is the integer to be tested.

Also there's no need to declare 3 and 5 as separate variables.  Just use 3 and 5.

Also also, you don't need to explicitly return true/false.  You can return the *result* of the modulus operation, which is itself true/false.

```
def is_divisible(num):
    return (num % 3 == 0) and (num % 5 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers explain the wrongs.
This code will work:

```
def is_divisible(number1):

    if (number1 % 3 == 0 and number1 % 5 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False


count_passed = 0
count_failed = 0
if (is_divisible(15) == True):
    print("Test #1 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #1 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(1) == False):
    print("Test #2 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #2 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(5) == False):
    print("Test #3 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #3 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1
if (is_divisible(0) == True):
    print("Test #4 passed")
    count_passed = count_passed + 1
else:
    print("Test #4 FAILED")
    count_failed = count_failed + 1

print(str(count_passed) + " tests passed and " + str(count_failed) + " tests failed")
```